# How to query Postgresql HSTORE in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql-9.1, hstore

I need to find all the notifications of a user of type interview.

`app/models/notification.rb`:

```rb
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  hstore_accessor(
    :data,
    path: :string,
    message: :string,
    type: :string
  )
end
```

Searching in google there's not too much information, so
I followed [this tutorial](http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-hstore-with-rails): but was unable to query the DB as stated there in the example:

```rb
User.where("preferences -> newsletter = :value", value: 'true')
```

I tried

```rb
user.notifications.where('data -> type = :key', key: Interview::NOTIFICATION_TYPE)
```

But I got the error:

```sql
*** ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "type" does not exist
LINE 1: ...WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = $1 AND (data -> type = 'IN...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = $1 AND (data -> type = 'INTERVIEW')`
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to query the HSTORE is being careful of the single quotes around the key, like this:

```rb
user.notifications.where(
  "data -> 'type' = :key",
  key: Interview::NOTIFICATION_TYPE
).count
```